# List "hardware" Network Interfaces Controllers

Tags: iproute2, ifconfig

When using `ifconfig` or `ip link show` commands, it lists not only hardware interfaces, but also software interfaces - I would expect only the physically interfaces?

Note: I am running on MacOS.

ip link show

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
anpi2: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
anpi1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
anpi0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en7: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
ap1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ...
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether <...>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether <...>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether <...>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether <...>
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 12 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1000
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun4: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun5: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun6: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
vlan0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1496
    options=6063<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether <...>
    vlan: 3 parent interface: en0
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en6: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether <...>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
en8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether <...>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
en10: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether <...>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Comment: en0, awdl0, llw0, utun0 anpi0 lo0, gif0, stf0 — what OS is this? I suspect MacOS; does it really have iproute2 package?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is MacOS. Is iproute2/ip not the successor to ifconfig?

Comment: In Linux, yes. I don't know about other systems. I think the original iproute2 package (circa 1999) is only for Linux and it was meant to use new Netlink kernel ABI and unleash the power of new Linux networking possibilities. There is iproute2mac, but **it is not iproute2**, it just mimicks some features of its interface. Also, I think networking utilities is not the right mean to ask about whether interface is physical or logical; they should not make any distinction *by design*. There should be system-specific way to tell; I know one for Linux, but don't know for Mac OS.

Comment: Right, thanks "t just mimicks some features"

Answer (score 0):

A quick way could be use *ifconfig* and grep the entries with an interrupt:

```
ifconfig |grep -B8 Interrupt
```